# Excel Pivot-table like functionality with R (plyr, ddplyr?)

Tags: r, plyr, dplyr, reshape, reshape2

I am hoping to use R to create pivot tables more quickly than with Excel (and reduce room for errors.

For example, if I have a data set like this:

```
id<-c("p","q","r","s","t","u","p","q","r","s","t","u")
time<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
foldchange<-rnorm(12)
log2foldchange<-rnorm(12)
p.value<-rnorm(12)
df<-data.frame(id,time,foldchange,log2foldchange,p.value)
```

and I want to sort the table out as I would in excel using pivot table to look like this (or as close as possible):
[image]

Any ideas? Cannot figure out how to do this (or anything that resembles this) from the examples on here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should `set.seed` if you're going to generate random numbers for an example

```
set.seed(1)
id<-c("p","q","r","s","t","u","p","q","r","s","t","u")
time<-c(0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,1)
foldchange<-rnorm(12)
log2foldchange<-rnorm(12)
p.value<-rnorm(12)
df<-data.frame(id,time,foldchange,log2foldchange,p.value)


reshape(df, dir = 'wide', idvar = 'id', timevar = 'time')

#   id foldchange.0 log2foldchange.0   p.value.0 foldchange.1 log2foldchange.1   p.value.1
# 1  p   -0.6264538      -0.62124058  0.61982575    0.4874291       0.82122120  1.35867955
# 2  q    0.1836433      -2.21469989 -0.05612874    0.7383247       0.59390132 -0.10278773
# 3  r   -0.8356286       1.12493092 -0.15579551    0.5757814       0.91897737  0.38767161
# 4  s    1.5952808      -0.04493361 -1.47075238   -0.3053884       0.78213630 -0.05380504
# 5  t    0.3295078      -0.01619026 -0.47815006    1.5117812       0.07456498 -1.37705956
# 6  u   -0.8204684       0.94383621  0.41794156    0.3898432      -1.98935170 -0.41499456
```

or simply

```
reshape(df, dir = 'wide')

#   id foldchange.0 log2foldchange.0   p.value.0 foldchange.1 log2foldchange.1   p.value.1
# 1  p   -0.6264538      -0.62124058  0.61982575    0.4874291       0.82122120  1.35867955
# 2  q    0.1836433      -2.21469989 -0.05612874    0.7383247       0.59390132 -0.10278773
# 3  r   -0.8356286       1.12493092 -0.15579551    0.5757814       0.91897737  0.38767161
# 4  s    1.5952808      -0.04493361 -1.47075238   -0.3053884       0.78213630 -0.05380504
# 5  t    0.3295078      -0.01619026 -0.47815006    1.5117812       0.07456498 -1.37705956
# 6  u   -0.8204684       0.94383621  0.41794156    0.3898432      -1.98935170 -0.41499456
```

very straight-forward, right @data.table?

Comment: Wow, how embarrassingly easy! Thanks rawr!

Answer (score 2):

Using [`data.table v1.9.5`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Installation), this is quite straightforward:

```
require(data.table) # v1.9.5+
dcast(setDT(df), id ~ time, value.var = names(df)[3:5])
```

PS: I'm assuming that p-values are just for the sake of it here.. since they are -ve / > 1. You should be generating random values from uniform distribution.

Comment: Hi, yes, the p-values here are just for the sake of it. I have tried your suggestion but I am getting an error message: "Error in .subset2(x, i, exact = exact) : 
  recursive indexing failed at level 2
In addition: Warning message:
In if (!(value.var %in% names(data))) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used". help!

Comment: You seem to have loaded `reshape2` after `data.table`. Either load `reshape2` before `data.table` or don't load `reshape2` at all.. and should work with 1.9.5.

Answer (score 0):

And with the less intuitive `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
library(dplyr); library(tidyr)
df %>% gather(name, value, c(-id, -time)) %>% mutate(new=paste(name, time, sep=".")) %>% 
  select(-time, -name) %>% spread(new, value)
```

***The logic is the following:***

Transpose the data for `foldchange` to `p.value`
this is done with the code `df %>% gather(name, value, c(-id, -time))`.

Next concatenate the variables you want to have as `column labels` in excel this is done with the `mutate(new=paste(name, time, sep="."))` part

And finally transpose the concatenated variable via `spread(new, value)` having first selected the columns you are interested in.

Depending on how you would them sorted (the columns) you could also try

```
df %>% gather(name, value, c(-id, -time)) %>% mutate(new=paste(time, name, sep=".")) %>% 
  select(-time, -name) %>% spread(new, value)
```

The difference is `mutate(new=paste(time, name, sep="."))`